# Triangles vanishing from view when moved

Tags: glut

I am writing a program to draw a square when the user click in mouse then user can move it up, down, left and right. The problem when user move it the object is hide

any one can help me.

this is sample of code

```
    #include <GL/glut.h>      
    #include<iostream.h>

    #define ORTHO_SCALE 10.

    GLint triangle_vertices[] = {15, 20,30, 20,10, 15};
    GLint triangle_vertices2[] = {50, 70,80, 90,100, 130};

    struct {
        struct {
            struct {
                GLfloat x, y;
            } pos;
            GLfloat rot;
        } triangle;
    } sceneinfo;
    void clearScreen()
    {

            glutSwapBuffers();

        glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        int ver[]={38,0,1143,0,1143,800,38,1105};
        glPushMatrix();
        glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );


        glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 0, ver);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glPopMatrix();


            glutSwapBuffers();

    }
    void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
    {
        if(btn==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
            exit(0);
        if(btn==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
        {   
            glutSwapBuffers();

            glPushMatrix();



            glTranslatef(sceneinfo.triangle.pos.x, sceneinfo.triangle.pos.y, 0);



            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 0, triangle_vertices2);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

            glPopMatrix();

            glutSwapBuffers();
        }

    }
    void display(void);
    void special(int key, int x, int y);
    void init (void)
    {
        glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);  // Set display-window color to white.

        glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);       // Set projection parameters.

        gluOrtho2D (0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);

        glutCreateWindow("test");

        init();

        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutSpecialFunc(special);
        glutMouseFunc(mouse);
        glutMainLoop();

        return 0;
    }

    void display(void)
    {

        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);//set color of object


        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



        glPushMatrix();



        glTranslatef(sceneinfo.triangle.pos.x, sceneinfo.triangle.pos.y, 0.);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 0, triangle_vertices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glPopMatrix();

        glutSwapBuffers();
    }


    void special(int key, int x, int y)
    {
        switch(key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            sceneinfo.triangle.pos.x -= 0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            sceneinfo.triangle.pos.x += 0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            sceneinfo.triangle.pos.y += 0.2;
            break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            sceneinfo.triangle.pos.y -= 0.2;
            break;
        }

    glutPostRedisplay();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used glut but I can see two potential issues:

1. You probably shouldn't be drawing in your `mouse()` function. Also you're swapping buffers twice here which is not going to produce desirable results.
2. You don't appear to be initialising `sceneinfo` anywhere, though that would affect rendering from the start.

Next steps: Initialise `sceneinfo` so you know it contains valid values and remove the drawing code from the mouse() function. If you still have an issue I'd use a debugger (or write out to a log in the worst case) to see what's happening with `sceneinfo.triangle.pos` — it could be growing much faster than you expect depending on how keyboard input is handled.

Comment: problem not in sceneinfo.triangle.pos my problem how i can redraw all object in new position.

Comment: I've only just noticed that you're also swapping the buffers and drawing in `clearscreen()` as well, you should remove that too. It should only be used to clear depth, render and any other buffers used in the rendering process.